# Labels show like a string array and not individual

Tags: asp.net, angular, highcharts, label

I try to make a highcharts dashboard with Asp.Net and Angular but when i try to make the chart with data from Asp.net labels appear as a string array in every slice of the chart and the legend name appear "slice" and i don't know why.I noticed that they appare like this only when i use "name" here:" name:allData.map(x=>x['name'])"

[image]

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { Order } from 'src/app/shared/order';
import {Customer} from 'src/app/shared/customer';
import {SalesDataService} from '../../services/sales-data.service';
import * as moment from 'moment';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pie-chart',
  templateUrl: './pie-chart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pie-chart.component.css']
})
export class PieChartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private  _salesDataService:SalesDataService) { }
 



  @Input() inputData:any;
  @Input()  limit:number;
  orderModel:Order[];
customerName:any;
  highcharts=Highcharts;
  
  public  options: any = {
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'pie'
     },
    title: {
    text: ''
     },
     plotOptions: {
       pie: {
       innerSize:'50%',
       dataLabels: {
      enabled:true,
      
      
      },
      showInLegend: true
       },
    
    
    tooltip:{
      pointFormat: '{name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
       
       },
      
    
      series: [{
       name:'',
        data:[ ],
      }],
    }


  
  
  ngOnInit() {
    

    this.parseChartData(this.inputData,this.limit);
   
    
  }


 parseChartData(res:any,limit? :number){
   console.log('response:',res);
   const allData=res.slice(0,limit);
   console.log('allData(slice):', allData);




 this.options.series=[{data:allData.map(x=>x['total']),
  name:allData.map(x=>x['name'])
}]



 Highcharts.chart('container2',this.options);
}
}
```

Live Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/rwL45ypc/

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because the pie series is slightly different than the others (for example line). The legend is created from its points (slices), not series as usual. So in order to set the name of each slice, you need to specify a name for each point.

```js
  series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    showInLegend: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Name1',
        y: 12
      },
      {
        name: 'Name2',
        y: 12
      },
      {
        name: 'Name3',
        y: 12
      }, {
        name: 'Name4',
        y: 12
      }
    ]
  }]
```

**Live demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hecL5kfm/

Comment: How to specify  a name for each point if i get data from Asp.Net?

Comment: Then you need to parse the data that you got from Asp.Net before putting it to your chart. You might also parsing them in one of the chart's events - for example on chart.load. Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1pLy7s23/ API references: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load, https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: I used chart events and now i have labels name and legend but they still appear 
connected. Ex: "ReadyCleaners,ReadyBakery ".

Comment: You mean, you got them as one string? If so you could just split that string. In JavaScript, you could achieve that with the `String.split(',')`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: My chart look like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rwL45ypc/  and i try to use  string.split but didn't work.

Comment: That's happening because you are assigning the entire array instead of a certain element. You can find a live demo in another thread that you created, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63254595/labels-string-from-asp-net-does-not-distributed-in-the-highchart/63259844#63259844